# Python pandas grouping according to a column, counting the cumulative value of its corresponding column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have had to deal with some problems today with python.

According to the sales area grouping, the corresponding shipments are accumulated and the shipment results are rounded. The value of a large area is NULL or empty, hoping to skip the statistics. The output csv file needs to have a large area + sales area + shipment volume + Message

[image]

```html
Id, Message, region, shipping volume, sales area
1, natural, AAA, 25.02, 111
2, Nature, BBB, 63.22, 222
3, China, CCC, 554.21, 333
4, yes, AAA, 63.22, NULL
5, large, NULL, 645.55, 222
6, DAD ,,, 333
7, large, BBB, 69.22, 222
8, NULL, DDD, NULL, 444
```

I did try:

[image]

Result:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import math
  
df = pd.read \ _csv (r'G: \\ 360MoveData \\ Users \\ Hasee \\ Desktop \\ Business List.csv ')
  
 #Discard missing values
 # df = df.dropna (axis = 0, subset = \ ["Sales Area", "erp average daily shipment amount" \])
  
for i in range (len (df)):
  if (df \ ['Sales Area' \] \ [i \] == '' or df \ ['Sales Area' \] \ [i \] == "NULL"):
   df = df.drop (i)
  
 #Rounded up  
  
 #df \ _sum = df.groupby ('Sales Area'). agg ({"Shipping Volume": sum}). reset \ _index ()
df \ _sum = df.groupby ("Sales Area"). agg ({"Shipping Volume": sum})
  
 #df \ _sum = df.insert (3, "Area name", df \ _sum ('Area'))
  
df \ _sum.to \ _csv (r'G: \\ 360MoveData \\ Users \\ Hasee \\ Desktop \\ Count1.csv ')
```

Problems:
1. I don't know how to add the district list.
2. I want to use math.ceil () to round the sales area and the value of the manifest, I do not know how to add it.
3. The first line is 0.0, which should be caused by NULL value and null value, how to avoid it.

Comment: Instead of images, Can you provide the sample data ? Would be great if you can provide Column header in English.

Comment: Id, Message, region, shipping volume, sales region
1, natural, AAA, 25.02, 111
2, Nature, BBB, 63.22, 222
3, China, CCC, 554.21, 333
4, yes, AAA, 63.22, NULL
5, large, NULL, 645.55, 222
6, DAD ,,, 333
7, large, BBB, 69.22, 222
8, NULL, DDD, NULL, 444

Comment: This is my sample data

Comment: Please provide the `Business List.csv` file.

Comment: This is the first time I have used stackoverflow. Do you see the data above to make you understand my needs? Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: I want to count the number of shipping volumes based on the sales area and region grouping (there are some data in the middle are null and blank), round the result value, and finally add the message column to output to another csv file,
At first I planned to write in C #, but it seemed a bit difficult. Now I encountered some problems with pandas, specifically above. Thank you very much

Comment: Please share your expected output also. I have answered your question. If you provide expected output, I can edit my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `groupby` as follows

#### 1. read csv into dataframe by trimming the whitespaces.

```py
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/prince/Downloads/test2.csv', sep=',', skipinitialspace=True)
```

Output is

```
Id  Message region  shipping volume  sales area
  1  natural    AAA            25.02       111.0
  2   Nature    BBB            63.22       222.0
  3    China    CCC           554.21       333.0
  4      yes    AAA            63.22         NaN
  5    large    NaN           645.55       222.0
  6     DAD     NaN              NaN       333.0
  7    large    BBB            69.22       222.0
  8      NaN    DDD              NaN       444.0
```

#### 2. Now drop NaN values

```py
df = df.dropna()
```

Output is

```
Id  Message region  shipping volume  sales area
  1  natural    AAA            25.02       111.0
  2   Nature    BBB            63.22       222.0
  3    China    CCC           554.21       333.0
  7    large    BBB            69.22       222.0
```

#### 3. Now do the groupby

in your question, you are doing groupby on `Sales Area`

```
df = df.groupby ("sales area", as_index=False). agg ({"shipping volume": 'sum'})
```

Which will give the output

```
sales area  shipping volume
      111.0            25.02
      222.0           132.44
      333.0           554.21
```

#### 4. If you want to include other columns in `aggregate` do as follows

```
df.groupby ("sales area", as_index=False). agg ({"shipping volume": 'sum', 'Message' : 'first', 'region' : 'first'})
```

which will give you the below output.

```
sales area  shipping volume  Message region
      111.0            25.02  natural    AAA
      222.0           132.44   Nature    BBB
      333.0           554.21    China    CCC
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help me answer. I may not describe my problem clearly. What I hope is to add two columns to your result: Message and region. I do n’t know how to do it.

Comment: I updated my answer, as per my understandings. Please check it.